# Check if URL targets Action (vs. file/etc)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to determine the best way to determine if a URL (as seen in the `global.asax`) is for an action. I'm wanting to exclude EVERYTHING else...i.e. a request to a bundle would fail as well as a request for a file.

It seems clunky and dirty to check to make sure the request isn't for a file/directory/bundle/etc. I'm hoping to be able to instead JUST check to see if it's an action, but I'm having issues coming up with what that test would look like.

Just FYI, in case it's relevant. I'm working on some internationalization of a site and I'm needing to filter the `Request` objects so that I only fiddle with the one for the initial request.

Comment: What do you mean by "as seen in the global.asax"?

Comment: @OskarLindberg similar to as seen on TV :)! Sorry jk, I just meant that I was in the `global.asax` so that someone can know what objects are available for use.